# What is the meaning of Malformed message in flutter? When and Why it's coming?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

When I code in a flutter. Many times the message appears in console named Malformed Message. No extra information is coming with it. Many times after some debugging I was able to crack the problem. But still, I was not able to find the exact reason behind its appearance. Please tell me why and when it is coming.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i only known log "Malformed message" was from `json.decode()` or `jsonDecode()`.

No idea how to handle(try/catch got nothing), and method still could get json decode result. Console just sometimes show "Malformed message".

Really weird....

Comment: i got it, try do not used over one isolate in method.